# Does timedelta added to date consider leap year?

Tags: python, date, datetime

Example Suppose for a given date, when we add timedelta(days=180), and get the new date, does it consider the leap year and calculate the new date? Or do we exclusively calculate the leap year of the current date whether Feb has 28 / 29 days and get the new date accordingly in python datetime.datetime object?

Comment: Did you try it?  What happened?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it out:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime(2012, 2, 27)
print(dt + timedelta(3))  # March 1st
```

If it didn't handle February 29th, I would expect this to say March 2nd.  So yes, Python's datetime knows about leap years.

Answer (score 1):

And one must be very careful using +timedelta(days=365).

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

dt = datetime(2012, 2, 27)
print (dt+timedelta(days=365)) # 2013-02-26

dt = datetime(2013, 2, 27)
print(dt + timedelta(3))  #  2013-03-02
```

Comment: the accepted answer is misleading! python knows the date but it looks to me timedelta cannot calculate the date correctly if there is a leap year during that period.

Comment: Timedelta does take leap year into account. Programmers have to be careful not to just add 365 and think that it will add 1 year. It won't if it is a leap year (as 2012 was). Python is literal, as it should be.